# crash log SIGABRT after selecting picture with UIImagePicker

Tags: ios

Could someone help me and explain the following crash log?

I'm building my first (iOS) app and incidentally got this crash after selecting (and zooming) a picture from  my PhotoLibrary.

Looking at the log, it seems to crash a bit later, though.

I'm new to the crash logs, could someone point out the exact reason/location of the crash for me to learn how to read this?
Are code fragments necessary for analysis?

Thanks in advance!

```
Incident Identifier: 806191F3-8C7A-4B77-B395-192E7C63AD12
CrashReporter Key:   ec9cb673f6ebb95077c5b905e3b9417a68d15d19
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         Mijn Kinderen [23756]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/0ED97506-C765-4D19-B3B1-6A04AFCABBB8/Mijn Kinderen.app/Mijn Kinderen
Identifier:      Mijn Kinderen
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-06-26 15:44:20.011 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x358b588f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37c5c259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358b5789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   Foundation                      0x3539d3a3 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 91
4   UIKit                           0x33556807 -[UIDatePickerView _updateBitsForDate:forced:andReload:animateIfNeeded:] + 147
5   UIKit                           0x334756c5 -[UIDatePickerView _setDate:animated:forced:] + 349
6   UIKit                           0x33475563 -[UIDatePickerView setDate:animated:] + 31
7   UIKit                           0x33556385 -[UIDatePicker setDate:] + 37
8   Mijn Kinderen                   0x000e2611 -[MKWijzigGebeurtenisViewController viewDidLoad] (MKWijzigGebeurtenisViewController.m:68)
9   UIKit                           0x33322c8b -[UIViewController view] + 167
10  UIKit                           0x33347481 -[UIViewController nextResponder] + 21
11  UIKit                           0x3330bbd5 -[UIResponder _containsResponder:] + 37
12  UIKit                           0x333ce359 -[UINavigationController defaultFirstResponder] + 57
13  UIKit                           0x333143b5 -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 25
14  UIKit                           0x33314263 -[UIResponder(Internal) _promoteDeepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 31
15  UIKit                           0x333ce31f -[UIWindowController transitionViewDidStart:] + 83
16  UIKit                           0x333836cb -[UITransitionView _didStartTransition] + 71
17  UIKit                           0x3338300f -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 999
18  UIKit                           0x333ccc05 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 4937
19  UIKit                           0x33426d71 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 1733
20  UIKit                           0x33388d85 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 757
21  UIKit                           0x33388d85 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 757
22  Mijn Kinderen                   0x000e303f -[MKWijzigGebeurtenisViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] (MKWijzigGebeurtenisViewController.m:180)
23  UIKit                           0x33554c5b -[UIImagePickerController _imagePickerDidCompleteWithInfo:] + 111
24  PhotoLibrary                    0x31593079 PLNotifyImagePickerOfImageAvailability + 45
25  PhotoLibrary                    0x315a4797 -[PLUICameraViewController cameraView:photoSaved:] + 131
26  PhotoLibrary                    0x315d28db -[PLCameraView cropOverlay:didFinishSaving:] + 227
27  CoreFoundation                  0x358141fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
28  Foundation                      0x353d8747 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 351
29  CoreFoundation                  0x35889ad3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3588929f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
31  CoreFoundation                  0x35888045 __CFRunLoopRun + 653
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3580b4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
33  CoreFoundation                  0x3580b36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
34  GraphicsServices                0x374a7439 GSEventRunModal + 137
35  UIKit                           0x33317cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
36  Mijn Kinderen                   0x000da36b main (main.m:16)
37  Mijn Kinderen                   0x000da310 start + 40


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3616b32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cb7208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cb0298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35c6df64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35c6b346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37c5c350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35c6b3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35c6b44a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35c6c81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37c5c2a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3580b506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3580b366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x374a7432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x33317cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  Mijn Kinderen                   0x000da364 main (main.m:16)
15  Mijn Kinderen                   0x000da308 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3615b3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34745f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34745c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3616b0d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c6c674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   WebCore                         0x316674e8 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 208
3   WebCore                         0x316677ec _ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 24
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35889b14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35887d50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3588816a __CFRunLoopRun + 946
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3580b49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3580b366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
9   WebCore                         0x3170ac9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c7872e _pthread_start + 314
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c785e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3616b068 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c78a46 _pthread_cond_wait + 634
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c787c2 pthread_cond_wait + 34
3   CoreMedia                       0x309ec868 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 268
4   MediaToolbox                    0x3670f3e6 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 22
5   CoreMedia                       0x30a0b8b4 figThreadMain + 168
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c7872e _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c785e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.camera.avcapturesession
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3615b004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3615b1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358893ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35888124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3580b49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3580b366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   AVFoundation                    0x357514d0 -[AVRunLoopCondition _waitInMode:untilDate:] + 348
7   AVFoundation                    0x3575136c -[AVRunLoopCondition waitUntilDate:inMode:] + 20
8   AVFoundation                    0x3573e13a -[AVCaptureSession _stopPreviewing] + 438
9   AVFoundation                    0x3573e2d6 -[AVCaptureSession _setRunning:] + 166
10  AVFoundation                    0x3573de42 -[AVCaptureSession stopRunning] + 274
11  PhotoLibrary                    0x31584590 __33-[PLCameraController stopPreview]_block_invoke_0 + 96
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x34742c52 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x34744d08 _dispatch_queue_drain + 268
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x34744b6e _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x347457e0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 204
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c72df4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c72cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3616bcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c72f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c72cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3eec2d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fed7a48
    r8: 0x002ee2f0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3f85b9b4     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fed7a3c      lr: 0x32cb720f      pc: 0x3616b32c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
   0xd9000 -    0xe6fff +Mijn Kinderen armv7  <f6dfc4f1cc023981af9c8c1f978561c8> /var/mobile/Applications/0ED97506-C765-4D19-B3B1-6A04AFCABBB8/Mijn Kinderen.app/Mijn Kinderen
0x2fed8000 - 0x2fef9fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30537000 - 0x305eafff  iTunesStore armv7  <b3c0cce5f8e632e18f841c32b68f57a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x305fd000 - 0x30603fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x306d7000 - 0x307fcfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30829000 - 0x30835fff  Accounts armv7  <79f22009b1173e1e81f70fc5c0410119> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x30836000 - 0x3083cfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x308bf000 - 0x308d4fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x309e6000 - 0x309e9fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x309ea000 - 0x30a32fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x30a6e000 - 0x30fb2fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3153d000 - 0x31660fff  PhotoLibrary armv7  <cff5092ea3343d8ebb2159c93c00ac68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x31661000 - 0x31e20fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31e33000 - 0x31f0bfff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31f0c000 - 0x320f0fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x320f1000 - 0x3213bfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32163000 - 0x32179fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x32185000 - 0x32342fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x324bb000 - 0x324ccfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x324d4000 - 0x324edfff  Twitter armv7  <8fe6d77b99b43d2287e9c51bc4b22456> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
0x326df000 - 0x327d0fff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x327e3000 - 0x327e6fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x32850000 - 0x32856fff  XPCObjects armv7  <dc568831fa5b3b22b673c62bc9d21d16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x32857000 - 0x32893fff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x328c0000 - 0x328e0fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3293d000 - 0x32949fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3294a000 - 0x3296dfff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3299b000 - 0x32a1efff  MapKit armv7  <e39706ac199134a497954e1f1d6d7245> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x32a1f000 - 0x32a69fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32a84000 - 0x32a8afff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x32a8d000 - 0x32a91fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32a92000 - 0x32a93fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x32a94000 - 0x32a95fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x32aa4000 - 0x32aa6fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32adc000 - 0x32c13fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <32bc794969e534df97a14dc4be228408> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x32c14000 - 0x32c40fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32c41000 - 0x32c65fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32c6a000 - 0x32cf6fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32d6d000 - 0x32d7efff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32dd9000 - 0x32de0fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x32dfc000 - 0x32dfdfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x32dfe000 - 0x32e01fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32e02000 - 0x32ea8fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32ee9000 - 0x32f24fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x332e6000 - 0x33788fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33789000 - 0x337b5fff  ACTFramework armv7  <0bc67086eb7b31d090bb4c9c7a54bfb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ACTFramework.framework/ACTFramework
0x338de000 - 0x33923fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x33962000 - 0x33967fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33989000 - 0x3399cfff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x339a9000 - 0x33a06fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x33a0c000 - 0x33b7ffff  MediaPlayer armv7  <63cdf8f9c66d36e7a4e69e2f6cae854f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x33ba1000 - 0x33beafff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33d2d000 - 0x33d33fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x33e19000 - 0x33e23fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x341d9000 - 0x341e8fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x341e9000 - 0x341eefff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x341f5000 - 0x341fffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34290000 - 0x34294fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x342d9000 - 0x342fefff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x34333000 - 0x34339fff  MediaStream armv7  <d3473621f67036dda5ecabeb14c62b4e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x3433a000 - 0x34350fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x343a7000 - 0x343e5fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34487000 - 0x344b0fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x344f0000 - 0x34546fff  GMM armv7  <6b2f7e1aa6be3d69b4c4cf54ed960602> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x34556000 - 0x3469ffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x346a0000 - 0x346a0fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x346a1000 - 0x346acfff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x346c8000 - 0x346fffff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3473d000 - 0x34741fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34742000 - 0x34758fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x34780000 - 0x347d1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x347d2000 - 0x347d9fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x347f9000 - 0x3480afff  AirTraffic armv7  <c9eb888c1bd1322cbda5b01d41be0c7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x348a4000 - 0x348a5fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x348c7000 - 0x348d3fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x348ec000 - 0x34904fff  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <c73a4b4b38ae3702bc1feae489d31634> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x34905000 - 0x3490dfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3490e000 - 0x34912fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34a9d000 - 0x34ab1fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34e82000 - 0x34ec6fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34ef8000 - 0x34f05fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x350a8000 - 0x3517ffff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x35180000 - 0x351fffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x352de000 - 0x352e2fff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x35334000 - 0x354b2fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x354d5000 - 0x354dbfff  IAP armv7  <17eddbf5590d3cb88d4acbda27447f5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x354ef000 - 0x35581fff  HomeSharing armv7  <11ca6ed6f8c0377aba1d3e03484c380f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x3558e000 - 0x3565efff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x356de000 - 0x35794fff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x35795000 - 0x3579bfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3579f000 - 0x357e8fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x357e9000 - 0x357ecfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x357fc000 - 0x35913fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35a9e000 - 0x35af6fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x35af9000 - 0x35af9fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x35b02000 - 0x35b11fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x35b12000 - 0x35b12fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x35b15000 - 0x35b24fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35c67000 - 0x35c6efff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x35c95000 - 0x35ce1fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35d64000 - 0x35e0efff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35e30000 - 0x35e33fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
```

------------------- cut here

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint? Can you post some code where you use `setDate:` ?

Comment: Post the viewDidLoad of MKWijzigGebeurtenisViewController

Comment: Post this method as well: `PLCameraView cropOverlay:didFinishSaving:]`

Comment: im guessing the problem is in `[MKWijzigGebeurtenisViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]` can you please post this delegate method.

Comment: @KDaker i did'nt seem to be able to put the code fragments in a comment, so i put them in an 'answer'. See below. Is there a command to notify all the above commenters?

Comment: i think they get notified automatically as long as they have an entry in the comments...

Comment: I honestly don't see any problem with the posted code, perhaps the other guys might see something i can't... have you been able to reproduce this crash? if so, the console error would be a lot more helpful... It could have something to do with the your DatePicker

Comment: put a breakpoint on this line: self.wijzigDatum.date = _gebeurtenis.datum;

and check that the _gebeurtenis.datum object is a valid NSDate object.

Answer (score 0):

The requested pieces of code:
**MKWijzigGebeurtenisViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    self.title = @"Wijzig gebeurtenis";

    // view controller toevoegen als delegate van UItextview
    _wijzigOpmerkingen.delegate = self;

    // minimum datum voor picker samenstellen
    _wijzigDatum.minimumDate = self.minimumDatumVoorPicker;
    _wijzigDatum.maximumDate = vandaag();

    // Set an image as the background of a UITableView called 'tableView'
    NSString *bestandsnaamAchtergrond = nil;
    if ([_gebeurtenis.bijKind.geslacht isEqualToString:@"J"]) {
        bestandsnaamAchtergrond = @"LightBlueBathTowel.jpg";
    }
    else if ([_gebeurtenis.bijKind.geslacht isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
        bestandsnaamAchtergrond = @"PinkBathTowel.jpg";
    }

    UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bestandsnaamAchtergrond]];
    bg.alpha = 0.4;
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:bg];

    self.wijzigOmschrijving.text = _gebeurtenis.omschrijving;
    self.wijzigOpmerkingen.text = _gebeurtenis.opmerking;
    self.wijzigDatum.date = _gebeurtenis.datum;
    self.wijzigFoto.image = _gebeurtenis.foto.foto;
}
```

and

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *originalImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *gewijzigdeImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    UIImage *gekozenImage;

    if (gewijzigdeImage == nil) {
        gekozenImage = originalImage;
    }
    else {
        gekozenImage = gewijzigdeImage;
    }

    self.wijzigFoto.image = gekozenImage;
}
```

Hope this helps. I don't seem to be using the PLCameraView cropOverlay:didFinishSaving:] could it be this is invoked by other classes like UIImagePickerView?

Sorry for the Dutch comments and thanks again for your feedback!